# how to get value from custom input component in directive in anglar7?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `angular7` app in which i have a `custom` `input` component which is calling at multiple positions like this
`component.html`

`component.ts`

```
  handleChange(value) {
   this.payment.collectedAmount = value;
   this.calculateRemainingBalance();
  }
```

Now i have directive in which i will be formatting input's component's value but currently i am just getting the value inside `directive` on `custom` component like this

```
    @Input() currencyValue: any;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      // this.el.nativeElement.focus();
      console.log('currency value : ',this.currencyValue)
    }

    @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target']) onfocus(){
       console.log('in focus');
    }
```

Now when i run the app and loads the page so `directive` logs this line `console.log('currency value : ',this.currencyValue)` only once when page loads and then it is not logging any more neither in `ngAfterViewInit` nor in `HostListener`. How can i get the value from this `custom` input component inside my `directive` ?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz that reproduces the issue?

Comment: If your directive is applied to a input, you can inject NgControl in constructor. You can subscribe to valueChanges